# Apache configuring ssl

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https

I have the following

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost 55.55.55.55:443>
#<VirtualHost *:443>
   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert/myCert.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key/myKey.key
   SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/bundle/bundle.crt

   ServerAdmin info@myDomain.com
   ServerName www.myDomain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
 </VirtualHost>
```

I have a Java program that accesses the above url using https.  When I comment out the VirtualHost line with the ip address and uncomment the wildcard line, the Java program gives me a "peer not authenticated" exception.  When I leave it as is, the Java program works as expected.  The main reason I want to do it this way is I have other subdomains where I define other  sections.

What is the issue with using the wildcard VirtualHost line?

Comment: Java changed their security policy recently. follow instructions here https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml to make sure that it is not just java.

Comment: I'm confused because it is serving the same cert in both instances.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that by defining the IP address This directive was being used.  However, when I used the *:443 directive I have the servername as www.myDomain.com and I am not accessing the www when I try to access the page so this virtualhost block is not being used.  But rather there was a `_default:443` directive in a different config file that didn't define the `SSLCACertificateFile` directive so the CA cert wasn't being sent, so Java wasn't getting the CA cert.

My solution was: to create a *:443 directive with `ServerName` without the `www`.